# How to chop inside a for-loop in Twig

Tags: twig, refactoring

This is a refactoring question. The code works as is, I'm just not happy with it in an aesthetical sense.
I would like to know if the conditional inside the loop can be written in a shorter, more readable way or maybe can be stripped away?

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for element in list %}
  {% if loop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %} {# open first row #}

  {% if i > 2 %} {# new row every 3 elements #}
    {% set i = 0 %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="{{ element.url }}">
  {% else %}
    {% set i = i+1 %}
    <img src="{{ element.url }}">
  {% endif %}

  {% if loop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have a look at [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user DarkBee said, have a look into batch.

```
{% for element in list|batch(3) %}
 .....
 .....
{% endfor %}
```

Just to have an example on this page.

[Batch-Docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

Regards